# Alarm with Sqlite database

Tags: alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

hey  i am developing an reminder app so i managed to create the alarm from the table inside the database and with the notification with cols (ReminderID,ReminderTitle,activeOrNot,day,week,......)

here is the deal am setting the alarm from the table with for loop and it only query the setted active alarm

but the thing is when the notification pops to the user when he click on the notification and to map the auto increment Reminder ID in the database just need the notification id which appeared to the user set before and set the alarm not active so when setting further alarms it doesn't see the already notified alarm

am using Pendingintent.getbrodcast to set the notification

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i got the solution for this thing after 4 days

when you are setting the alarm you should have the receiver class and when assigning the PendingIntent

i put extras the notif id for the intent and i created a class to receive the bundle with the extras and it contains the notif ID and updated to the database